# Sorting a text file according to first column in Python

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, text, file-io

I'm new to Python. I have a text file containing 3 columns and first column consists of numbers. I want to sort lines of this txt in an increasing order. I tried this:

```
lines=[line for line in inputFile if line.strip()]
lines.sort()
```

However, file is sorted non numerically, but alphabetically. For example 1,11,12,13,14,...19,2,21,.... How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from converting each line to a tuple of (number, string, string), and then sorting that list?

Comment: I forgot to mention: also there are X and Y values in first column, so I cant read them as number,string,string.

Comment: Please provide some sample input, so we know exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: Assume this is just the first column of the file: 1;4;5;X;Y;X;3;2;... going like this. I got 2 chars and others are just numbers. I want the output to be 1;2;3;4;5.....;X;Y

Comment: When you say "first column", do you mean "first line"?  Also, it may be best to put your example input in your question; not everyone reads all the comments.

Comment: If [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) is an option for you to use I can highly recommend it.

Comment: bruno desthuilliers' answer worked very well. Thank you very much people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "columns" (BTW if it's a csv or tsv file, check the `csv` module in the standard lib), but arknave's comment is the right answer. A simplistic, naïve and brittle implementation (assuming tab-separated values):

```
def convert(line):
    x, y, z = line.strip().split("\t")
    if x.isdigit():
        x = int(x)
    return x, y, z

lines = sorted(convert(line) for line in infile if line.strip())
```

**CAVEAT :** this relies on an implementation detail of CPython 2.7 and may not work as expected with another python version or implementation (AFAIK it will break with CPython 3.x).

A more robust (but possibly slower) solution:

```
def mycmp(t1, t2):
    x, y = t1[0], t2[0]
    x_int = x.isdigit()
    y_int = y.isdigit()
    if x_int and y_int:
        x, y = map(int, (x, y))
    if (x_int and y_int) or (not x_int and not y_int):
        return cmp(x, y)
    elif x_int:
        # digits must come before non-digits
        return -1
    else:
        # non-digits must come after digits
        return 1

lines = sorted((line for line in infile if line.strip()), cmp=mycmp)
```

Comment: File is a .txt file, it has 3 entries in each line separated by tabs. I want to sort it according to the first entry in each row. However, they are not all int's. I also have 2 chars X and Y in first column. So int(x) might not work.

Comment: @BaturayKaya: cf the updated code snippet - you just need to check if first "column" can be converted to an int - but please pay attention to the warning.

Comment: Added a more robust solution

Comment: I think the `cmp` argument is deprecated in favor of the `key` argument.

Comment: At least, Python 3 doesn't support that `cmp` argument: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort

Answer (score 0):

It is interpreting the values as strings, so indeed `19` is "less than" `2`. You can convert them to `int` to properly sort them by numeric value.

```
lines=[map(int,line) for line in inputFile if line.strip()]
lines.sort()
```

Or if you don't want to modify the values, and would like to leave them as strings:

```
lines.sort(key=lambda i : int(i))
```

Comment: I tried this but it gave "invalid literal for int() with base 10:''

Comment: Do you have only values like "1", "2", or do you have decimals like "1.5", 3.2", etc?

Comment: I have integers 1,2,3 and two char's like X and Y. I want the result to be: 1 2 3 4 5...... X Y

Answer (score -1):

One could also use the key argument to the sort function:

```
def get_key(a):
  return [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in a.split('\t')]

lines = sorted((line for line in infile if line.strip()), key=get_key)
```

**EDIT:** To get around the implementation detail that sorts ints before strings,one could use the following key function (this will, however, cause the characters to remain unsorted):

```
def get_key(a):
  return [int(x) if x.isdigit() else float('inf') for x in a.split('\t')]

lines = sorted((line for line in infile if line.strip()), key=get_key)
```

Comment: cf the caveat in my own answer: this relies on the implementation sorting ints before strings.